# What is best way for editing and creating theme for nop commerce?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, styles, themes, nopcommerce

Since my previous question didn't meet standards, i am posting short version of it. I already tried chrome developer tools to edit style of theme but it is not enough when i have new views entered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use developer just to change code, then i save it and upload on FTP. I just wonder if there is any other way.

Comment: I currently don't have any editor, i am testing all that i know to find the best, but i still didn't find any, are you saying that chrome developer tools is best option to use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create a new theme for nopcommerce is:
- Copy the folder "Theme" with your new "theme name". 
- Change the css file to do what you want. 
- Change in the administrative panel selected theme for your new theme.

To change HTML structure will be necessary change "cshtml" files at "Presentation" folder in "Nop.Web" Project

To make your life easier, you must use the Visual Studio IDE

Answer (score 0):

changing your code in chrome does not change the actual code on your page.
what you want to do is to connect your webserver via FTP (as WINSCP) (or wherever nop is runnin) and edit the files containing your websites style codes with your editor.

Comment: actually i'd say: no. use notepad++ and edit the files directly. you can not edit your websites style using chromes dev-tools. it only changes your actual view of the page.

Comment: i do use notepad++ sometimes, but i need something like dev-tools that can show what i am editing and how does it looks.

Comment: copy your changes and paste them in the stylesheet using noteoad++. don't forget about the other browsers though.

Comment: Okay, will do that way then. Thanks for answers.